# Store the result of a Dynamic Query in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I know this question has been asked, and I already found some solutions in internet.. but I still can not make it work properly.

So.. I have to make a SELECT query and store the result in a variable (I DONT want a table variable).
My problem is that the name of the table is also a variable. The table name changes accordingly to a WHILE, here is my code:

```
DECLARE @numRecord INT;
DECLARE @maxMacNumber INT;
SET @maxMacNumber = 500;
DECLARE @mac INT;
SET @mac = 0;
DECLARE @res FLOAT;
DECLARE @ap INT;
SET @ap = 0;
DECLARE @apString VARCHAR(2);
DECLARE @numRecordString VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500);
DECLARE @varDefinition NVARCHAR(200);

WHILE @mac <= @maxMacNumber
BEGIN
     SET @numRecord = 6 + @mac * 390;
     SET @ap = 0;
     WHILE @ap < 2
     BEGIN
          SELECT @apString = CONVERT(VARCHAR,@ap);
          SELECT @numRecordString = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @numRecord);
          SELECT @rssiString = CONVERT(VARCHAR, @rssi); 
          SET @tablename = 'APDB.dbo.AP' + @apString;
          SET @sql = 'SELECT RSSI FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE ID=' + @numRecordString;
          SET @varDefinition = N'@res FLOAT OUTPUT';
          EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @varDefinition, @res = @res OUTPUT;
          PRINT @res;
          -- HERE I WILL DO SOMETHING WITH @res
      END;
END;
```

The problem is that it doesn't print anything when I do `PRINT @res`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the relevant SQL code:

```
      SET @sql = 'SELECT RSSI FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE ID=' + @numRecordString;
      SET @varDefinition = N'@res FLOAT OUTPUT';
      EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @varDefinition, @res = @res OUTPUT;
      PRINT @res;
```

You are never setting `@res` in the SQL.  Try this:

```
      SET @sql = 'SELECT @res = RSSI FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE ID=' + @numRecordString;
      SET @varDefinition = N'@res FLOAT OUTPUT';
      EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @varDefinition, @res = @res OUTPUT;
      PRINT @res;
```